# iPhone localization does not work

Tags: iphone, localization

I'm trying to localize my App.

Steps:

1. Create a Localizable.strings file with Xcode 5.1
2. Add a language from Project-Info
3. Press localize in utility of Localizable.strings file and add a language
4. Use NSlocalizedString function

It work in a blank App but did not work when use in my App, infact it write the key instead the value.

What can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure your string is localized and that you publish your app with the correct locations selected (when you submit, choose the countries you want the app to be localized in, otherwise the localization is ignored).